# Transforming 2D points on to a regular grid or lattice

Tags: color, geometric-transform, dimension-reduction

I have a set of points in 2D generated by doing a `DimensionReduce` on a list of colors:

```
colors = RandomColor[100];
coords = DimensionReduce[colors, 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
ListPlot[Thread[Style[coords, colors, PointSize -> .05]]]
```

[image]

However, I would like to arrange these points into a regular 2D grid (or other lattice) while maintaining neighbourhoods as much as possible, to make something like this:

[image]

(this is just a mockup)

Is there a function to provide this transformation? Or am I better off writing something to shuffle the colors in a grid to minimise neighbor distances? Here's my crude attempt at such a process:

```
dm = DistanceMatrix[colors, DistanceFunction -> ColorDistance];
g = System`GridGraph[{10, 10}, VertexSize -> .8];
adj = AdjacencyMatrix@g;
vneighbors = 
  GatherBy[Position[adj // Normal, 1], First][[;; , ;; , 2]];
vlabels = Range[100];
Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
   VertexStyle -> colors[[vlabels[[#2]]]]] &, g, Range[100]]
```

[image]

```
Do[
  While[{swapi, swapj} = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 2]; swapi == swapj];
  cost = Total@
     dm[[vlabels[[swapi]], vlabels[[vneighbors[[swapi]]]]]] + 
    Total@dm[[vlabels[[swapj]], vlabels[[vneighbors[[swapj]]]]]];
  swapcost = 
   Total@dm[[vlabels[[swapj]], vlabels[[vneighbors[[swapi]]]]]] + 
    Total@dm[[vlabels[[swapi]], vlabels[[vneighbors[[swapj]]]]]];
  If[cost > swapcost, temp = vlabels[[swapi]]; 
   vlabels[[swapi]] = vlabels[[swapj]]; vlabels[[swapj]] = temp], 
  10000];
Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, 
   VertexStyle -> colors[[vlabels[[#2]]]]] &, g, Range[100]]
```

[image]

Is something like this the best solution to the problem? There must be something cleverer Mathematica can give me.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

It is hard to understand what you mean, but here is a simple take. `Round` can take an arbitrary step. That makes a grid of an arbitrary step.

```
colors=RandomColor[100];
coords=DimensionReduce[colors,2,Method->"TSNE"];

gridStep=.5;

ListPlot[
    Thread[Style[Round[coords,gridStep],colors]],
PlotStyle->PointSize[.03],
Frame->True,
FrameTicks->{Range[-10,10,gridStep],Range[-10,10,gridStep]},
GridLines->{Range[-10,10,gridStep],Range[-10,10,gridStep]},
GridLinesStyle->Directive[Gray, Dashed]]
```

Comment: You're right the question was super unclear. I've made a mockup to try and illustrate what I'm after. I want to transform the data such that it's uniformly distributed across a grid or lattice.